# Swagger using the same model but different examples

Tags: yaml, swagger

My API can retun 200 ok or 400, an error occurred. I want them both to use the same model but different examples. In my code below, I want my 200 Info to say something like "All ok" and 400's Info "Not ok".

```
 responses:
        '200':
          description: >-
            Invoice received for processing but beware of potentional warnings
            and information
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Response'
        '400':
          description: Invoice could not be processed due to fatal errors
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Response'

  Response:
    type: object
    properties:
      Info:
        type: string
          information
      Messages:
        type: object
        properties:
          Fatal:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
          Warning:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
          Information:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenAPI 2.0, responses support the `examples` keyword to specify response examples for different HTTP status codes and media types.

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: >-
            Invoice received for processing but beware of potential warnings
            and information
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Response'
          examples:
            application/json:
              Info: OK
            # Or using JSON syntax for the example value:
            # application/json: {"Info": "OK"}

        '400':
          description: Invoice could not be processed due to fatal errors
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Response'
          examples:
            application/json:
              Info: Oops
              Messages:
                Fatal:
                  - Houston, we have a problem
            # Or using JSON syntax for the example value:
            # application/json:
            #   {
            #     "Info": "Oops",
            #     "Messages": [
            #       {
            #         "Fatal": [
            #           {"Custom error": "Houston, we have a problem"}
            #         ]
            #       }
            #     ]
            #   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But, as for example Fatal is an array of kv pairs, how do I write something like. Fatal: [ "Custom error": "Houston, we have a problem"]

Comment: Do you mean `Fatal: { "Custom error": "Houston, we have a problem" }` with curly braces instead of square brackets? Key-value pairs in square brackets `["a": "b"]` is not a valid JSON syntax.